# Socket Scanning for Android

Tags: java, android, sockets, timeout

:)  I'm trying to make an Android app which will scan an entire network for a specific open port.  I am using Android Studio (Windows) and the emulator.  I am able to scan the network for 90 seconds before my program stops running.  I don't receive any logcat errors and I lose the stack and program counter in the debugger.  I cannot restart the program without first restarting the emulator.  It looks like I lose any connection I had to the emulator.

I should also mention that removing the socket connect line results in the task running indefinitely.  Has anyone experienced this kind of time out before?

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated!!

Jenny

```
private class getNetworkState extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer> {
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {

        for (int subnet2 = 216; subnet2 < 220; subnet2++)
        {
            for (int subnet = 0; subnet < 255; subnet++)
            {
                // open a tcp socket
                String server = String.format("192.168.%d.%d", subnet2, subnet);
                Socket socket = new Socket();
                try
                {
                    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(server, port), timeOut);
                    System.out.println("Network state of " + server + " == " + socket.isConnected());
                    socket.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Network state of " + server + " == " + e);
                }
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

How often are you seeing exceptions in socket.connect(...)?  The way the code exists, failed connects will throw an Exception and the socket will not be closed.

I think a better practice would be to close the socket in a finally block.  If the cause of your problems is a ton of open sockets, this might help clear up the issue.

```
private class getNetworkState extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Integer> {
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {

        for (int subnet2 = 216; subnet2 < 220; subnet2++)
        {
            for (int subnet = 0; subnet < 255; subnet++)
            {
                // open a tcp socket
                String server = String.format("192.168.%d.%d", subnet2, subnet);
                Socket socket = new Socket();
                try
                {
                    socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(server, port), timeOut);
                    System.out.println("Network state of " + server + " == " + socket.isConnected());
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Network state of " + server + " == " + e);
                } finally {
                    socket.close();
                }
            }
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the relpy!  I see a failed connection exception ~90% of the time.  I added a finally{} section to close the socket but see the same behavior.  I do think this is the right path though because testing a little further if I continuously connect a known open port I don't see a time out but connecting to a known closed port I do see the time out.  -- Jenny

Comment: Hi Jenny, did you ever figure out what the problem was?

Comment: Thanks for checking in!  I haven't been able to make and significant progress on this issue.  I have a report into Google to try and clear up if this is a emulator issue since I can't reproduce the timeout when running on a mobile device.  I am also looking into setting up my environment in Ubuntu to see if it might be a Windows issue.